# Visual Studio Code Extension with own panels with HTML form elements

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to develop an extension for VSC. The user should add images (selection via combobox) and some values for the attributes like title. I don't want to use snippets. In Atom packages it is possible to create views/dialogs. There are functions in `atom.workspace` like `addTopPanel()` and `addModalPanel()`.

In the Docs I've found *contribution points* there are listed examples for keyboard shortcut, menus, showing messages and open file open dialogs, but nothing about own panels/view.

Is it possible in VSC to create own panels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, I think this is still not possible. The [extensibility model](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/overview) for VS Code doesn't include it. VS Code is able to be as stable as it is because the extension host runs in its own separate process (not allowing you to directly interact with the DOM, so can only interact through the API). Many people are asking for the ability to build custom UI components for extending it, so I'm sure it will come soon.

Comment: Thanks,  for your answer. So I'll wait for custom UI and have to be patient while fixing the bugs of my atom package by using Atom's dev tools. :-|

Answer (score 2):

Panels and modals are possible in vscode using WebView's. Use `<style>` tags to adjust a view's size and positioning.

See the [WebView documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview) and a [WebView example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/webview-sample).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the viewContainers and specify the location
e.g

```
 "viewsContainers": {
      "panel": [
        {
          "id": "panel-tasks",
          "title": "PANEL VIEW",
          "icon": "media/logo_square.svg"
        }
      ]
    },
```